# I can't use datalist's change event in vue.js, change event is not working

Tags: vue.js, html-datalist

I try to work with bootstrap-vue and I gonna make autocomplete, but I have some troubling, How can I do that

```
<b-form-input :list="id"></b-form-input>
<datalist :id="id" @change="d => on_select(d)"  >
      <option v-for="size in sizes" :key="size"   :data-value="size" :value="size"  />
</datalist>
```

```
on_select (t) {
   debugger
   console.log(t)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `@change` event to `input` element.

html:

```
<div id="app">
   <b-form-input list="my-list-id" id="input-with-list" @input="changeSelectedItem" ></b-form-input>
   <datalist id="my-list-id">
       <option v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
   </datalist>
</div>
```

component:

```
 data() {
   return {
     options: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
   }
 },
 methods: {
   changeSelectedItem(e) {
      this.option = e
   }
 }
```

if you want to get the index of item, or other data about it, you can loop over your `size` list.

see it https://jsfiddle.net/Nanif/L3h5f18x/42/

Comment: @LionGreat, please let me know if it help you.

Comment: Its show list, but need change event, i have data with key and name, on user selecting I need selected item key

Comment: Look at the changes in my answer.